# A vegan alternative to Quorn?

Tags: vegetarian, vegan

It seems that almost all meat replacements in the UK have eggs. Are there any good vegan alternatives?

Comment: Is there a specific use you are looking for?  What I use depends on the texture I want.

Comment: yes, I am looking for something that doesn't require a lot of extra work to make tasty (i.e. not tofu), and comes as slices for sandwiches, or burgers, etc.

Comment: Did you try vegetables instead of using highly processed factory plastic food as meat replacement? Beans? Lentils? Grains?

Comment: Yeah, I mostly use fresh ingredients, but sometimes it is handy to have something pre-prepared.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Also see @Pulse's answer. Check out the China town for 'vegetarian food', they have all sort of fake meat from chicken to beef, from abalone to fish, all made of modified tofu fibres.

Comment: I'll definitely go and have a look. Do you have any recommended brands or products that you've tried?

Comment: I am not sure of the exact brands as I live in the far east where food is produced. My advice would be to go by the taiwanese brands. the quality control's better...

Answer (score 7):

Seitan is good, and very easy to make at home. (Just a little time consuming.)

My measurements are not metric, so if anyone can translate, I'd appreciate it.

Bring to a boil about a gallon of water. Add to that any particular flavors you like. I usually add dried basil and oregano, some vegetable broth (about a cup), vegan worchestershire or soy sauce, and dried minced onions.

While waiting for that to boil, take one cup of wheat gluten. Add just about a cup of water and mix until combined. You'll have a ball of sticky dough. Put that ball under running cold water for a minute, then knead underwater for five minutes. You'll end up with something firm and rubbery.

Drop into the boiling broth. Watch it for about five minutes to make sure it doesn't stick to the bottom of the pot, then leave it to simmer for two hours.

That's all!

Comment: thanks for the recipe! I do like seitan, but never have tried making it myself.

Comment: Wheat gluten is not easy or cheap to acquire in the UK, in my experience.

Answer (score 5):

In the UK, you may want to have a look at [the Vegan Society](http://www.vegansociety.com/afssearch.aspx). They [endorse](http://www.vegansociety.com/trademarksearch.aspx) a range of products which can be recognized through their sunflower logo.

I'm rather fond of products made by a company named [The Redwood Wholefood Company](http://www.redwoodfoods.co.uk/), they produce quite an interesting range of vegan meat substitutes, including ready-to-use slices.

You should be able to find these products at a wholefood shop; Hollands & Baretts carry them sometimes (and they may have other vegan offerings as well).

Answer (score 5):

Quorn have introduced some vegan products themselves since that question was asked (as of 2017).

Answer (score 4):

What about [Tofu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tofu) It's essentially the coagulated soy milk, pressed into blocsk. It's great in all kinds of recipes, especially Asian dishes, it really absorbs the flavours from the rest of the ingredients.

Comment: I'm into tofu, but in this case I'm looking more for something instant, like a sandwich slice or burger.

Comment: Are you open to tofu preparations that you do ahead of time, resulting in a sandwich slice you can later slap on bread? If so, marinate, slice real thin, spread on a greased cookie sheet, and roast in a 400 degree (F) oven for 10 minutes or so.

Answer (score 3):

Along Pulse's lines, [seitan](http://www.ivu.org/faq/specialities.html) may work well.  Depending on the dish, sometimes I prefer seitan's texture over tofu.  In the US, you can find it in many health food stores in the refrigerated section, often by tofu, and sometimes regular grocery stores if you're lucky.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for lunchmeat sliced thingies, I recommend the following companies:

- Gardein
- Tofurky
- Yves

Answer (score 2):

GO TO HOLLAND AND BARETTS they are soooo good. Get the vegetarian's choice sausages and burgers they are vegan and their texture is far better than anything i've tasted before. They also do lots of vegan cheeses, ham, pepperoni. It depends what holland and barrett store you go to some also have fresh pasties and sausage rolls etc.

Answer (score 2):

For mince my favourite is Sainsbury's own brand. They use eggs in other meat-like products but not in the mince soya protein. It is by far the best I've tried and is about £1.5 for a whole bag. You find it in the frozen section.

For everything else Fry's Family is my first choice. You can find them in most health shops and at online at Ocado.